# How to pass API endpoint URL containing \ to

Tags: url, httprequest, curl, encodingutil, url-encode

I'm trying to pass the given URL to the setEndpoint method, but I'm getting an error.

This particular API URL contains backslash and maybe that's the problem because the code works fine with other URLs which don't have backslashes.

Please let me know how do we encode/decode this to pass it as an argument.

```
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

 String url='https://api.example.com/s1/output?filter\[abc\]\[\]=xyz';

 req.setEndpoint(url);
```

Also, this URL works completely fine with the `curl` command!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect that something is going sideways because you're not properly escaping the non-safe URL characters (like `\` and `[`); in a URL, they must be in a certain style known as "percent encoding". Here's how I'd approach your problem:

```
ApexPages.PageReference ref = new ApexPages.PageReference('https://api.example.com/output');
ref.getParameters().put('filter\\[abc\\]\\[\\]', 'xyz');
String theUrl = ref.getUrl();
req.setEndpoint(theUrl);
```

This produces output like:

```
https://api.example.com/output?filter%5C%5Babc%5C%5D%5C%5B%5C%5D=xyz
```

Things like "curl" are smart enough to do this for you, but in Salesforce, you always need to use either EncodingUtils.urlEncode or PageReference.

Edit: The URL doesn't have backslashes in it; the backslashes that were used are required by the shell for `curl` to properly detect the brackets. So, simply removing those should fix the issue:

```
ApexPages.PageReference ref = new ApexPages.PageReference('https://api.example.com/output');
ref.getParameters().put('filter[abc][]', 'xyz');
String theUrl = ref.getUrl();
req.setEndpoint(theUrl);
```

Comment: @SnehaJagtap There's no backslashes in that URL. Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: no clue why backslashes aren't showing up here! Trying again -  "https://api.example.com/s1/output?filter\[abc\]\[\]=xyz"

Comment: I have edited the url in the question. That's the exact URL! So sorry for inconvenience :)

Comment: @SnehaJagtap No, I think you're misunderstanding. I don't think the URL needs it; the backslashes are to escape the `[` and `]` in the *shell*, so they're needed for `curl`, but not for the server you're calling. Please read my edited version and give it a try.